Data don't be updated after fetching data in global app vue3.js without components in twig symfony render
I need vue3 on a single page and I can't update the value of useNoms with vue3 without components...
The App.js without components to be more cleared:
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return {
            grille:"",
            useNoms: "",
            errored: false
            }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.fetchData();
        this.useNomsFct();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData(){
            axios.get("http://myAPI/url")
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
                this.grille=response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
                this.errored = true;
            //})
            //.finally(function () {
            // always executed
            });
            return this.grille;
        },
        useNomsFct(){
            if(this.grille.useNoms==="non"){
                this.useNoms="non";
                console.log('non' + this.grille);
            } else {
                this.useNoms="oui";
                console.log('oui'+this.grille);
            }
            return this.useNoms;
        },
    },  
});
app.mount('#app');

Why the return value this.useNoms is not defined, the condition if(this.grille.useNoms==="non") is not matching because property this.grille is not updated, how can I do this ?
The HTML with the CDNs directly in the HTML:
<script nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}" src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p><label for="useNoms">Oui</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="oui" v-model="useNoms"/></p>
    <p>
    <label for="useNoms">Non</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="non" v-model="useNoms"/></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

Data coming from the API by fetch with Axios:
useEntraineurs: "non"
useJockeys: "oui"
useNoms: "non"
useProprietaires: "non"

I am trying to display a radio button based on the value "oui" ou "non"

The mounted code block runs synchronously.  since you don't await the result of the axios call, this.useNomsFct() executes before the API result has returned.  See async functions explanation.

I resolved this problem: Data don't be refreshed by Async Await function, Now i'll get another Ticket, but I think I'm forced to integrate Components for using props. There's no solution without component for this part of the script
